# How to disable Soft Keyboard Pop up and enable InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE in edittext from Android?

Tags: android, popup, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to write a code in Android to disable the Softkeyboard pop up and enable the line break in Edittext , so this will help me read a long paragraph in Edittext and the soft keyboard should not Pop-while doing scrolling in the edittext.

I took few approaches and it created the new line in the edittext but while touching to EditText or doing scrolling the Soft Keyboard Pop-up in the Screen.

**My Approach.**

EditText object - : et

```
   et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

This code creating new line in EditText but not disabling the SoftKeyBoard Pop-up.

Please let me know  what could be the solution. Please suggest me.

Comment: Setting the input type won't ever disable the soft keyboard.  The input type is a hint to the soft keyboard telling it what type of data the user will be writing, so it can display appropriate keys (numerics, letter, change in symbols like @ or www. keys) and features (such as turning on/off autocorrect).  ANd you almost NEVER want to set the type to NULL, it screws stuff up.  You also almost never want to set the input type anywhere but the xml, as changing it causes issues if a keyboard is already up.

Comment: In addition, if you want to just scroll text, don't use an edit text.  Use a text view and put it in a scroll view.